# Dark mode toggle remember when i toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i have a question about toggle for dark mode wanna when i toggle i refresh to save checked or not for dark mode
When i toggle to dark mode i want to remember when refresh page i tried few solution but dont works

- javascript *

```js
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 

const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('[data-switch-dark]');

const enableDarkMode = () => {
  // 1. Add the class to the body
  document.body.classList.add('dark');
  // 2. Update darkMode in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  // 1. Remove the class from the body
  document.body.classList.remove('dark');
  // 2. Update darkMode in localStorage 
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}
 
// If the user already visited and enabled darkMode
// start things off with it on
if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
  enableDarkMode();
}

// When someone clicks the button
darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // get their darkMode setting
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 
  
  // if it not current enabled, enable it
  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();
  // if it has been enabled, turn it off  
  } else {  
    disableDarkMode(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: This previous answer of mine might help you, it does just that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62635541/1913729

Comment: Example: when i am on dark mode to display Swith to light mode and when i am on Light mode to display swith to dark mode

Comment: Yes this change to dark mode but toggle remains same

Comment: I edited it: https://shrt.tf/so_62635314.html

Comment: @blex i dont understand on your link works fine but add code on localhost dont work same if i am light mode and refresh page change to dark mode

Comment: With the same code? Any errors in the console? Is the value saved to localStorage, if you look into it?

Comment: Same code i copy paste in console localStorage dont show error

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, locally, it works for me... I don't know 

Comment: I dont know on your link works fine but add this code on localhost always change to dark mode when i am on light mode

Comment: On my page you have both because it used to be called "blackOut" (that's what the other asker was using), and then, since you call it darkmode (which I find better), I changed it. You copied the code before I made the change :)

Comment: Ok i dont know why doesnt work

Comment: I have no clue... 